# Checkbox code not working?

Tags: php, sql, json

I have the following code that is supposed to accept checkbox data from the user, and store it in a sql database via php, but something is not koshir, and I cannot seem to figure out where I went wrong :(  This is what I have so far :

Main page form code :

```
<?php
            $salesman = json_decode($invoice['salesman'], true);
                if(empty($salesman)){
                for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>';
                }
                } else {
                foreach($salesman as $k => $v){
                $i = $k+1;
                if($v == "checked") {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if checked, check.
                } else {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'"/> '.$i.'<br>'; // if not checked, don't check.
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Sql page code :

```
$salesman = $data['data-invoice-salesman']; // this is an array
                $salesman_array[]; // create new array
                for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ // loop from 1 to 5
                if(in_array($i, $salesman)){ // if value exists (has been selected), stack 'checked', if not, stack ''.
                    $salesman_array[] = "checked";
                } else {
                    $salesman_array[] = "";
                }
                }
                $salesman_json = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, json_encode($salesman_array)); // encode the array into JSON and then escape it.
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code to see if it returns anything.

Comment: Just a hint, if the variable has only values like `checked` and `''`, you don't need an `IF`, you can just echo the variable.

Comment: I am having an issue with $salesman_array[] I think, for some odd reason it does not like

Comment: You create new array with `= array()` or `= []`. Replace with `$salesman_array = array();` But, commenting out that line should work since you are just adding items with `$salesman_array[] =`

Comment: @FirstOne if that were the case, then the OP should be getting notices about it (if checking for errors), and associated with the version of PHP if less than 5.4

Comment: errors found with above with this site :http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: um... ok so what would you like us to do, check and debug what you posted on that site? what's your PHP version? and did error reporting throw you what's on YOUR site/server?

Comment: ok, the array suggestion from @FirstOne fixed the saving to the db, but it is not loading the checkboxes still.  The db code saved is "["","checked","checked","",""]"

Comment: @FirstOne if you post the array() as the answer, I will check it off as correct, Thanks!

Comment: @Steven, thanks, but since you had to change something else, you should [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34537787/edit) and add the full solution and maybe a working code. It might help future readers.

Comment: @FirstOne I updated my answer with your suggested code, will not add my other fix because it is not relevant to anything but my code specifically, and would just confuse users

Comment: @RyanVincent The issue is solved, I didn't name my array correctly.  Check the sql page code to see how I handle checked or not checked, I basically look at the json data to see if a checkbox has been checked or not, if not I save the value as ""

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that, this code:

```
$salesman_array[];
```

Should be :

```
$salesman_array = array();
```

---

Thanks to @FirstOne for his comment, that helped fix the array and get the saving part correct.  The other issue was just a matter of naming scheme for calling the data back.

Answer (score -1):

What you forgot to do was initialize the array. $array[] is for adding a NEW element. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the array hasn't been initialized, so PHP makes a fuss.

All you have to do is add this line:

```
$salesmen_array = [];
```

(before your other code, in the function)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Let me fix that

Comment: Just a note: Removing the incorrect code (`$var[];`) would itself fix the problem. You just need to use `$var = array();` if the variable had a previous non-array value or if you want to empty it. [This code](https://3v4l.org/d66WM) might help you understand what I mean.